# iTunes Podcast XML elements/tags

Tags: xml, rss, itunes, podcast

A number of years ago I created a custom PHP script for generating a podcast XML file for a Podcast i had submitted for inclusion into iTunes.

At the time, i'd managed to find a document detailing the various iTunes custom tags. Fast forward 4+ years, and i now cannot find any of it in one place online, not even from Apple.

All i could find was references to changes to the iTunes Podcast file spec, but again these only refer to changes/additions to tags.

Just to point out, i've tried web searches, but thus far have only found the odd thing here or there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The documentation for the iTunes specific tags can be found [here](https://help.apple.com/itc/podcasts_connect/#/itcb54353390).